# Ctrl+Del doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

While editing I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow keys</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow keys</kbd>... extensively to work at word level

However somehow in Chrome <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> works properly but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> doesn't do anything. That happens in any textboxes. Is there anyway to make it work?

Comment: This will depend heavily on the javascript settings and the web pages you're using, which can override the keybindings.

Comment: @BruceBecker it's not related to any webpages, since it happens in any textboxes like the address bar or the input box in settings page

Comment: @PHPst definitely not. Still does nothing when I press Ctrl+Del. [Ctrl+Del on text doesn't work in Chrome, not even in native chrome elements](https://superuser.com/q/1477869/241386), [I can't use Ctrl-Del to delete the next word](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B04yuH51YuvCc/?hl=iw)

Comment: @PHPst it's still not working in my Chrome version 81.0.4044.122

Comment: @PHPst I've just disabled all extensions and indeed it works. I've found the root cause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue has probably been fixed for some time. If you can't use it then it's because some extension has stolen it. You can browse `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` to check which one and disable or reassign the key if you want